# How to disable the developer option in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, developer-options

I have enabled developer options accidentally by clicking on **Settings > About Chrome > Application Version** 7 times.

I didn't find any option to disable this developer options. How to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag to show Developer options is stored on Chrome's shared preferences under the `developer` key, which can only be accessed with root access.

As shown on the source code:

1. [AboutChromeSettings](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/about_settings/AboutChromeSettings.java#91): tapping the Application Version 7 times calls `DeveloperSettings.setDeveloperSettingsEnabled()`
2. [DeveloperSettings](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/tracing/settings/DeveloperSettings.java#43): writes the boolean value `true` to `ChromePreferenceKeys.SETTINGS_DEVELOPER_ENABLED`
3. [ChromePreferenceKeys](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/chrome/browser/preferences/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/preferences/ChromePreferenceKeys.java#591): `SETTINGS_DEVELOPER_ENABLED` refers to the `developer` key in the shared preferences

To reset the flag:

- **With root access**

  Users can overwrite the value on the shared preferences directly

  1. Browse to `/data/data/com.android.chrome/shared_prefs/`
  2. Open `com.android.chrome_preferences.xml`
  3. Search the line `<boolean name="developer" value="true" />`
  4. Change the value to `"false"`
  5. Save the change
- **Without root access**

  Users can only use Android Settings' "Clear data" to reset the flag. **Note that this will also reset all Chrome's settings**.